# Using AOP and DI itself causes Spring ApplicationListener to be fired twice

Tags: java, spring, transactions, aop, event-listener

### Software versions

- Spring Version  5.3.18 and earlier
- JDK Version 1.8.0_202

### Overview

When I use Spring ApplicationListener, in order to prevent transaction invalidation, my ApplicationListener implementation class writes the following code (of course, the code can be written differently to avoid this problem), which will cause my listener to trigger twice after the event is published. I think it's not normal, but not sure if it's a bug, so I want to ask everyone's opinion.

```java
@Component
public class EventDemoListener implements ApplicationListener<EventDemo> {
    @Autowired
    DemoService1 demoService1;
    @Autowired
    DemoService2 demoService2;
    @Autowired
    EventDemoListener eventDemoListener;

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(EventDemo event) {
        eventDemoListener.testTransaction();
        System.out.println("receiver " + event.getMessage());
    }

    @Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class)
    public void testTransaction() {
        demoService1.doService();
        demoService2.doService();
    }
}
```

Through this demo project, this problem can be reproduced. Please read the README.md document before running.
https://github.com/ZiFeng-Wu/spring-study

### Analysis

1. After analysis, because here DI itself , When `EventDemoListener` is created, property filling will trigger `DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry#getSingleton(String, boolean)` in advance.
2. Then `singletonFactory.getObject()` executed in `getSingleton()` will cause the unproxyed `EventDemoListener` object to be put into `AbstractAutoProxyCreator#earlyProxyReferences`.
3. After the properties are filled, calling `AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory#initializeBean(String, Object, RootBeanDefinition)` and executing `ApplicationListenerDetector#postProcessAfterInitialization(Object, String)` will cause the unproxyed `EventDemoListener` object to be put into the `AbstractApplicationEventMulticaster.DefaultListenerRetriever#applicationListeners` container.

   [image]
4. Then when the event is published, execute `AbstractApplicationEventMulticaster.DefaultListenerRetriever#getApplicationListeners()`  and use `ApplicationListener<?> listener =beanFactory.getBean(listenerBeanName, ApplicationListener.class)` to obtain the listener is the proxied `EventDemoListener` object.
5. At this time, there are only unproxyed `EventDemoListener` object in the `applicationListeners` container, so the proxied `EventDemoListener` object will be added to the final returned allListeners collection, as shown in the figure below, which will eventually cause the listener to be triggered twice.

   [image]

Comment: Welcome to SO. I edited your question in order to reformat it a bit and also make your hidden inline images visible. You have done some nice digging here, but with only the interceptor code I cannot help you, because I need an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in order to reproduce your problem. A minimal GitHub project would be good. Please also edit the question, explaining what you actually want to achieve by self-injecting a bean and starting a transaction for your interceptor. Then notify me with another comment. Thank you very much.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! In order to prevent the internal call of the method from causing the transaction to fail, I injected itself and then used the injected instance to complete the method call. But when I wrote the following code I found that the listener will be triggered twice. I think it's not normal, but not sure if it's a bug? You can reproduce this problem through this demo project, the link is https://github.com/ZiFeng-Wu/spring-study. Thank you!

Comment: Some quick feedback, which I am going to delete again at some point: Thanks for the GitHub project. Today I am busy with a few other things, but I am not forgetting this one, and if nobody else answers first, I might get a chance to look into this during the weekend.

Comment: Thanks! Looking forward to your reply.

Comment: `java.io.FileNotFoundException: conf\spring-context.xml`. Please update the project in order to make it run correctly, i.e. either provide the XML config file or equivalent annotation-based configuration. Please also provide the database configuration. I am not going to re-type the text from the image in your screenshot on the GitHub read-me. Ideally, reconfigure the Maven project to use an in-memory DB like H2, and make sure the necessary data (if any) are inside there. I am not going to manually install MySQL or whatever, just to make your project run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Updated answer

Now with your updated GitHub project, I can reproduce the problem. It also occurs when using a Spring AOP aspect targeting the listener class, not just in the special case of self-injection + `@Transactional`. IMO, it is a Spring Core bug, which is why I created [PR #28322](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/pull/28322) in order to fix the [issue #28283](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/28283) you raised either before or after cross-posting here. You should have linked to that issue in your question, I just found it because I was searching for key words before creating an issue for it myself.

See also my comment in the issue, starting with [this one](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/28283#issuecomment-1094584772).

---

#### Original answer (for reference)

OK, in your main class I changed

```java
String configFile = "src/main/resources/spring-context.xml";
AbstractApplicationContext context = new FileSystemXmlApplicationContext(configFile);
```

to

```java
AbstractApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext("com.zifeng.spring");
```

Now the application starts, also without DB configuration. It simply prints:

```
receiver test
```

There is no exception. I.e., if for you it does not work, probably there is a bug in your XML configuration. But actually, you really do not need it, because you used component and service annotations already.

So if I need a database setup in order to reproduce this, please, like I said in my comment, update the project to provide an H2 configuration which works out of the box.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to push the conf directory. I have updated the project and replaced mysql with H2. You can run the entry class directly, thank you!

Comment: Thanks for the update. I could reproduce the issue, also in a Spring AOP scenario. I created a pull request with a solution. Maybe you want to build Spring and try for yourself. I already verified it locally. Please see my updated answer for details.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In fact, this problem can be reproduced by creating a proxy and self-injection for a listener class, but my business scenario uses transactions, so the code uses transactions. I will continue to pay attention to the submission of your code on spring-framwork. Thanks again!